# Balanced Payment configuration , unable to configure it

Tags: php, configuration, autoload, phar, balanced-payments

i am totally unable to configure it on my vertrigo/wamp server , i really do not know how to configure it , how to install phar , how to run queries , i have read the documentation on github.com/balanced/balanced-php/ and balancedpayments.com/ but have not find any luck i am stucked please help me to get out of it 
the documention i have seen on both sites still i am unable to complete it , what is meant by these queries 
If you don't have Composer install it:
$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
what is vendor\autoload.php where it is located 
some one please help me i really need to do this as soon as earlier

thanks so much in advance , will be waiting for kind responses

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/guides/quickstart/setup/?language=php and https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php give specific instructions on how to set up balanced-php, but I'll describe them again here. I also recommend you read through the documentation on https://getcomposer.org/ to better understand what Composer is and how to use it.

Running the following in your terminal will install Composer:

`curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

In your project's composer.json file, require balanced-php by adding:

```
{
    "require": {
        "balanced/balanced": "1.*"
    }
}
```

Run the following command to apply the changes to composer.json:

`php composer.phar update`

Now you can require the autoloader and initialize balanced-php and its dependencies:

```
<?php
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

\Httpful\Bootstrap::init();
\RESTful\Bootstrap::init();
\Balanced\Bootstrap::init();
?>
```

Lastly, configure the Balanced Settings with your API key secret so your application can perform authenticated API requests:

```
<?php
Balanced\Settings::$api_key = "ak-test-22IOkhevjZlmRP2do6CZixkkDshTiOjTV";
?>
```